# Get HTML Code of HTML File using PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a task of localserver 192.168.1.1. I want to fetch the data of a page

> 192.168.1.1/userRpm/SystemStatisticRpm.htm?Num_per_page=100

I want to display the HTML code returned by this file.

When I am running curl command on terminal like
**curl -u admin:admin PageURL** ( Its returning the code of page)

But when I am using PHP curl then its redirecting me to 192.168.1.1

Can anybody help me ?

My code is :

```
<?php
$json_url="http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/SystemStatisticRpm.htm?Num_per_page=100";
$username="admin";
$password="admin";
$ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type:application/json')); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

  $result=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/SystemStatisticRpm.htm?Num_per_page=100' );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.google.com');  //just a fake referer
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_POST,0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 20);

$htmlContent= curl_exec($ch1);
```

Comment: I got the html code displaying on my screen. Can I get few lines from this code.I mean I just want to get few array values(coming in Javascript array in head section) from this HTML ?

Comment: yes sure you can explode the html output at the required portion and get you code

Comment: My html code contains this code that is showing on the screen :
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var statList = new Array(
0, "192.168.1.179", "88-53-95-28-2B-AF", 194280, 101141053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, "192.168.1.170", "60-C5-47-10-37-FD", 132316, 65860791, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, "192.168.1.151", "68-5D-43-21-76-95", 9887, 3898646, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
</SCRIPT>
I want to fetch IP address and Mac addresses from this code.

Comment: First explode at <SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> then you will get the values in one array then try to explode that array or process it with php functions

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init("addrress");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Its still redirecting me to 192.168.1.1 instead of showing the code of file.

Comment: Try and wrap a <pre> around the output, or escaping the characters it's returning.